# Change the font sizes in the whole application

Tags: ios, swift, font-size

I have a lot of labels in my application. What is the best way to change all font sizes? For example:

```
func changeFontSize()
{
    var coefficient = 1.0
    switch device{
        case iPadPro:
            coefficient = 1.2
        case iPhone5:
            coefficient = 0.9
        case iPhone4:
            coefficient = 0.8
        ...
        updateFontSizeInApplication(coefficient)    
}
```

Is this possible? Should I set the coefficient each label on each controller, depending on the device?

Comment: You should use the `[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:]` method to set your label fonts so the user/iOS can choose which font size is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do extension for UIFont and implement method/s that will returns all your app font/fonts with scaled size.

```
extension UIFont {
    class func appFontName(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        guard let font = UIFont(name: "YourFontName", size: scaledSize(size)) else {
            return UIFont.systemFontOfSize(scaledSize(size))
        }
        return font
    }

    private class func scaledSize(size: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let coefficient = 1
        switch device { // pseudocode for checking device type
        case iPadPro:
            coefficient = 1.2
        case iPhone5:
            coefficient = 0.9
        case iPhone4:
            coefficient = 0.8
        }
        return size * coefficient
    }
}
```

Example usage :

```
let textField = UITextField()
textField.font = UIFont.appFontName(16) // on iPad it will be ~19
```

Hope it will inspire you ;)

Comment: How does this update the font of every current label in the app?

Comment: Ok, you're right. It's not a one-line code that changes every label in the application, but it's a way of using fonts in the whole application to make it scalable per device.